# How to wrap text with A element

Tags: jquery

I have html code

```
  <td id="MyNode">TextNode</td>
```

and would like to make it as

```
<td id="MyNode"><a href="http://www.domain.com">TextNode</a></td>
```

I have tried to use code below but what it does is add href attribute to TD element but I need to wrap text with A element.

```
 $('#MyNode').add('a').attr('href', 'http://www.domain.com/');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`.wrapInner()`**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/):

```
$('#MyNode').wrapInner('<a href="http://www.domain.com/"/>');
```